# how can I make a clause "OR" in a query cakephp2.3 with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, select, cakephp-2.0

Anyone know how I can make a query in cakephp using an OR clause to a database MongoDB?

I'm using:

```
 $produtos = $this->Anuncio->find('all',
        array('conditions' => 
          array('OR' => array(
               'nomeProduto'=> array('$regex' => (string)$pesq),
               'categoria'=> array('$regex' => (string)$pesq))
          ),
        ));
```

but is not working.

Comment: Why the double array? `array('conditions' => 
                array('OR' => array(
                   'nome LIKE' => '%'.(string)$pesq.'%',
                   'sobrenome LIKE' => '%'.(string)$pesq).'%'))
          )` doesn't work either?

Comment: yes, usually works in a mysql database.
  But in a MongoDB database does not work. Returns nothing.

Comment: so I believe that the OR clause, is made differently in a search for MongoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get it to work, it was so use '$ or' out instead of 'OR'.
So the research was as follows:

```
$produtos = $this->Anuncio->find('all',
        array('conditions' => 
          array('$or' => array(
               array('nomeProduto'=> array('$regex' => (string)$pesq)),
               array('categoria'=> array('$regex' => (string)$pesq)))
          ),
        ));
```